# Doctrine ORM retornando array[0] no find

Tags: php, doctrine-2, silex

Estou com uma dúvida.. 
Implementei o Doctrine com Silex, criei a entidade, o repository e o service, mas na hora de eu fazer uma busca com o findByEmail() por exemplo, para exibir o resultado tenho que usar $result[0]->getNome(). Teria alguma forma de remover esse [0] do find? o meu método Está assim:

```
public function fetchByEmail($email)
{
    $usuario = $this->em->getRepository($this->entity);

    return $usuario->findByEmail($email);

}
```

Se precisar de mais alguma informação é só me solicitar..
Grato

Comment: public function fetchByEmail($email)
{
    $usuario = $this->em->getRepository($this->entity);

    return $usuario->findByEmail($email)[0];

}, não resolveria seu problema?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Denis.. mas será que não existe uma outra forma de fazer isso sem ter que passar o [0] em algum lugar?

Comment: Estou pesquisando, é na verdade não sei nada sobre o Doctrine, respondi em comentário por quê sabia que a reposta da consulta é um array, daí a necessidade do [0]

Comment: Sim, tbm to o dia inteiro pesquisando.. não encontro referência nenhuma.. mas vamos continuar, deve ter alguma forma.. e tbm não sou muito bom com doctrine.. to começando agora...

Comment: poderia postar o código de findByEmail?

Comment: Esse é um método mágico do doctrine.. não fui eu quem fiz...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51906/discussion-between-denis-rudnei-de-souza-and-alexandro-zaleski).

Comment: Consegui resolver.. o problema é que o findBy do doctrine, retorna um array com outros arrays dentro, ai para retornar um único registro precisei usar o findOneBy ai resolveu meu problema.. Obrigado Denis pela ajuda..

Comment: De nada, você pode criar uma resposta para a sua própria pergunta e marcá-la como aceita para ajudar outras pessoas que tenham o mesmo problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver.. o problema é que o findBy do doctrine, retorna um array com outros arrays dentro, ai para retornar um único registro precisei usar o findOneBy ai resolveu meu problema. Segue o código abaixo:

```
public function fetchByEmail($email)
{
    $usuario = $this->em->getRepository($this->entity);

    return $usuario->findOneByEmail($email);

}
```